# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - Python 3.7

Tags: mysql, python, json, flask, python-3.7

Estoy haciendo un CRUD con Python 3.7 y Flask, ahora estoy en la parte del UPDATE, por lo que yo mando datos desde Angular 7 y los proceso python. Sin embargo a la hora de ejecutar el codigo me sale el siguiente error:

```
in actualizar_estatus
    status = data['estatus_usuario']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Mi codigo python:

```
@app.route('/updateStatus', methods = ["POST"])
def actualizar_estatus():
    conection = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root','root', 'users')
    data = request.json
    status = data['estatus_usuario']
    print(status)
    mail = data['email_usuario']
    print(data)
    cursor = conection.cursor()
    cursor.execute( "UPDATE administrador_usuarios SET estatus_usuario=%s WHERE email=%s",(status,mail))
    conection.commit()
    return json.dumps({"response":"ok"})
    conection.close()
```

Y esto es lo que recibo en la funcion de parte de Angular:

```
{'estatus_usuario': '1', 'email_usuario': 'erick.frias@dixa.com.mx'}
```

Que esta pasando?

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que estás confundiendo los Diccionarios con los Arrays.

Un diccionario tiene la forma sintáctica de este tipo:

```
diccionario_de_edades = {'Juan': 17, 'Ana': 14}
print(diccionario_de_edades['Juan'])
```

> 17

En cambio una lista o bien Array tiene esta forma sintáctica:

```
lista_de_nombres = ['Juan', 'Ana']
print(lista_de_nombres[1])
```

> 'Ana'

Seguramente al crear el objeto **data** lo hiciste en forma de Lista o Array en vez de en forma de Diccionario que es creo como tu quieres que sea.

Answer (score 0):

El error te lo marca porque estás intentando obtener un indice tipo `string` en una lista.

intenta usando esto para para obtener el cuerpo de una petición

`request.get_json()` o `request.json()` en lugar de `request.json`

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que tu data viene en formato `dict`:

```
{'estatus_usuario': '1', 'email_usuario': 'erick.frias@dixa.com.mx'}
```

Si estos datos vinieran dentro de un array, deberías hacer un `for` para recorrerlo y luego extraer los datos.

Tú estás intentando sacar sus datos como si fuese un array.

Lo que deberías hacer es:

```
status = data['estatus_usuario'] =====> status = data.get('estatus_usuario',{})
```